# How to know that the structured data I marked up is consistent enough with the content in the page?

Tags: google-search, search-results, schema.org, rich-snippets

I had rich snippets implemented (in JSON-LD) in my company's ecommerce website. 
I read some documents and someone noticed that if "the marked-up structured data is not representative of the main content of the page or potentially misleading.", then rich snippets will not display in search results.

How to know that the structured data I marked up is consistent enough with the content of the page? Are there any tools to detect this situation?

Answer (score 1):

Try the Google Structured Data Tool. Maybe you already have. 
https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool

down in the lower right click on "learn more about this tool" and below is first part of that. You also have to wait about a week after adding rich snippets until the Google Bots index your page(s).

> Prototype and Test Your Markup
>
> Using the features of this site and the Structured Data Testing Tool,
>   you can prototype, test, and make on-the-fly adjustments to your
>   markup.
>
> Prototype markup
>
> These steps describe a progressive approach to exploring and
>   prototyping markup:
>
> Start in the Search Gallery. The Search gallery illustrates rich
>   Search results for key schema.org data types, which include Rich Cards
>   and Rich Snippets. Each example's button loads the markup directly in
>   the Structured Data Testing Tool (SDTT). Explore the Data Type
>   reference. Here you'll see all the data types open for
>   implementation—indicating required and recommended fields, and
>   providing markup examples that load directly in the SDTT. Use the
>   Structured Data Testing Tool.